# How do I write the fizzbuzz function in Python 3 with an input value?

Tags: python-3.x, function, if-statement, fizzbuzz

I am writing a function fizzbuzz and what I want to do is input value and return it as fizz, buzz or fizzbuzz. However, there is a problem with my code. Whenever I run this, I just only get the first condition and it does not continue. Here is the code below for you:

```
a=int(input('Enter a number: '))

def fizzbuzz(a):

    if a % 3 == 0:

        return ('Fizz')

    elif a % 5 == 0:

        return ( 'Buzz' )

    elif a % 15 == 0:

        return ('Fizzbuzz')

    else:

        return a

print(fizzbuzz(a))
```

Comment: There's a python example of FizzBuzz on the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Be sure that your conditions are checked in the right order.

A Fizzbuzz number is also a Fizz (divisible by 3) and a Buzz (divisible by 5), just to be clear.
In the code you wrote if you ask the function if 15 is a Buzz, since it is the 1st check, you will get a positive result.

The condition you want to test here is not if a number is divisible by 15 but if a number is divisible by 3 and 5 at the same time.

Given this explanation you need to write conditions a bit differently:

```
a=int(input('Enter a number: '))

def fizzbuzz(a):
    if a % 3 == 0 and a % 5 == 0:
        return('Fizzbuzz')
    elif a % 3 == 0:
        return('Fizz')
    elif a % 5 == 0:
        return('Buzz')
    else:
        return a

print(fizzbuzz(a))
```

Comment: Hey so I changed from 15 to 3 and 5 and the code works. I dont need the range from 0 to 50 too but still, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
def fizzBuzz(n):
    for n in range(1,n+1):
        if n % 3 == 0 and n % 5 == 0:
            print('FizzBuzz')
        elif n % 3 == 0:
            print('Fizz')
        elif n % 5 == 0:
            print('Buzz')
        else:
            print(n)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input().strip())
    fizzBuzz(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the ordering of your if conditionals.

Consider that if `a` is divisible by 15 then it is also divisible by 3 and 5 and so your code will just enter the first conditional and not the one you want.

Arrange the conditionals in descending order of 15, 5, 3 etc. and you should see what you want.

Comment: The reason I wrote 15 is that I did not want to use the and operator. What I want to do is print fizzbuzz if that number is both divisible by 3 and 5 and since 15 is also divisible by them, I used 15 as a conditional. Am I wrong?